# Python: DictReader returning a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, csv

I'm using csv.DictReader() to read in a file. It actually returns a list of dictionaries, rather than a single dictionary. How can I force it to return a single dictionary or how can I merge the list of dictionaries it returns?

```
def agilent_e8361c_pna_read(file_loc):
    '''
    Load the '.s2p' file in to a dictionary.
    '''

    with open(file_loc) as f:
        # define the fields in the Agilent '.s2p' file
        col_names = ["f","s11","arg_s11","s21","arg_s21","s12","arg_s12","s22","arg_s22"]

        # read the data into a dictionary
        s2p_dicts = csv.DictReader(itertools.ifilter(n_input.is_comment, f), fieldnames=col_names, delimiter=' ')

    return s2p_dict
```

Ideally, the data would be initially read into a single dictionary and never need to be merged. It is a set of data. The columns belong together and are nonsense without the full set or a coherent subset. If DictReader isn't "pythonically" capable of this feat, I'll settle on just merging the list of dictionaries. This shouldn't be an uncommon thing that scientists and programmers alike want to do with a dataset.

Comment: Why would it return a single dictionary? It returns a dictionary for each row in the input file, that is what it is meant to do.

Comment: If you input file contains just *one* row, just select that one row: `return next(s2p_dict)`.

Comment: If it contains more than one row, how did you expect the data would be mapped to keys of the dictionary?

Comment: @MartijnPieters It sounds like you have your own very strong opinions about what I'd like to do here that doesn't match what I've stated. Very clearly, I am reading a file in containing columns of data. They are all part of one data set and so they should be contained within one dictionary.

Comment: Then please elaborate on how you'd like to see the dictionaries merged. What are the keys, what should the values be?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ideally, the data would be initially read into a single dictionary and never need to be merged. It is a set of data. The columns belong together and are nonsense without the full set or a coherent subset. If DictReader isn't "pythonically" capable of this feat, I'll settle on just merging the list of dictionaries. This shouldn't be an uncommon thing that scientists and programmers alike want to do with a dataset.

Comment: @nick_name if you've got a dataset like `[{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2}]`, what result would you expect?

Comment: I've taken a guess at what you wanted for a dataset instead; namely, a dictionary mapping to the *columns* in the file instead of the rows. `DictReader` gives you a per-row view on the data.

Comment: @nick_name: Note that the `DictReader` per-row approach is memory efficient; you can handle data one row at a time and discard the read data as you go along. That'll let you handle files millions of lines long. Handling the file *per column* instead, you now need to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is why I originally employed 'DictReader'. Is there an efficient way to merge all of the dictionaries into a single dictionary that you know of? What I've seen via searches are many very ugly methods for this. Surely, there is a pythonic way.

Comment: @nick_name: You keep talking about merging the dictionaries as if there is one obvious way. There is not. You need to be *explicit* how you want your data to be represented. I've given you one option in my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is obscenely clear what I mean here. The file contains columns of data. The columns have names, specifically 'col_names'. It would be great if I could take that entire list of dictionaries and create a single dictionary with the columns as keys.

Comment: @nick_name: Then my code below covers that case. This is the first time you made yourself clear; you could also have used sets for the data. You could have expected the values to be iterators instead, reading the data as requested. Etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a dict of `key:listOfValues` you could do something like this:

```
def transposeDict(listOfDicts):
    """Turn a list of dicts into a dict of lists.  Assumes all dicts in the list have the exact same keys."""

    keys = listOfDicts[0].iterkeys()
    return dict((key, [d[key] for d in listOfDicts]) for key in keys)
```

Alternatively, in python2.7 or later:

```
def transposeDict(listOfDicts):
    """Turn a list of dicts into a dict of lists.  Assumes all dicts in the list have the exact same keys."""

    keys = listOfDicts[0].iterkeys()
    return {key: [d[key] for d in listOfDicts] for key in keys}
```

Of course, this assumes that all dicts within the list have the exact same keys - which they will from a DictReader.

In general, if that isn't the case, you need to do something like

```
from collections import defaultdict

def transposeListOfDicts(listOfDicts):
    """Turn a list of dict into a dict of lists"""

    result = defaultdict(list)

    for d in listofDicts:
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            result[key].append(item)

    return result
```

If you want placeholders for missing values, then it looks like this:

```
def transposeListOfDicts(listOfDicts):
    keys = {}
    for d in listOfDicts:
        keys.update(d.iterkeys())

    return {key: [d.get(key, None) for d in listOfDicts] for key in keys}
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer. Thanks for taking your time to post it!

Answer (score 3):

`DictReader` takes each row a regular `csv.reader()` would return and turns that into a dictionary based on the fieldnames you passed in or read from the first row. This is by design.

If your input file contains just *one* row, return that by calling `next()` on the reader:

```
def agilent_e8361c_pna_read(file_loc):
    with open(file_loc) as f:
        col_names = ["f","s11","arg_s11","s21","arg_s21","s12","arg_s12","s22","arg_s22"]

        reader = csv.DictReader(itertools.ifilter(n_input.is_comment, f), fieldnames=col_names, delimiter=' ')
        return next(reader)
```

Do note that the `next()` call should be within the `while` block, otherwise the file will be closed before you could read from it.

If you need the rows merged into one dictionary, you need to state how you want to see the data merged. You can easily merged the rows into lists per key:

```
import csv

def agilent_e8361c_pna_read(file_loc):
    with open(file_loc) as f:
        col_names = ["f","s11","arg_s11","s21","arg_s21","s12","arg_s12","s22","arg_s22"]
        result = {k: [] for k in col_names}

        reader = csv.reader(itertools.ifilter(n_input.is_comment, f), fieldnames=col_names, delimiter=' ')
        for row in reader:
            for k, v in zip(col_names, row):
                result[k].append(v)

        return result
```

We don't need a `DictReader` anymore at that point, as we are not building a dictionary per row here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is the most elegant solution incase anyone ever has this problem.

```
def agilent_e8361c_pna_read(file_loc):
    '''
    Load the '.s2p file in to a dictionary.
    '''

    with open(file_loc) as f:
        # read the data into a dictionary
        rows = csv.reader(itertools.ifilter(n_input.is_comment, f), delimiter=' ')

        # transpose data
        cols = transpose(rows)

        # create a dictionary with intuitive key names
        col_names = ["f","s11","arg_s11","s21","arg_s21","s12","arg_s12","s22","arg_s22"]
        s2p_dict = dict(zip(col_names,cols))

    return s2p_dict

def transpose(l):
    return map(list, zip(*l))
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the items in a `dict` are always returned in the same order (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), so you could see columns getting mixed up.  

Also, the comment "convert list of lists into a dictionary" is inaccurate, as `rows` is not a `list` of `list`s, and the return value of `transpose()` is a `list`, not a `dict`.

Comment: @RoadieRich You're right--that comment was defunct. So you basically would never want to use a dictionary to store ordered pairs?

Comment: @RoadieRich Actually, the order will NOT change if all you do is iteration.

Comment: No it won't, but it's bad practice to rely on a behavior that doesn't apply in every case.  There is an ordereddict that makes some guarantees, but its update semantics isn't always what you want.

A dictionary is intended to let you look up a value, given a key.  The key can be thought of a lot like a variable name: if your key is a part of a data point, you're probably misusing it.  For ordered pairs, consider using a list of tuples, or a list of a custom class.

Comment: Also, you can't guarantee that you're just iterating here: you don't know what `csv.reader` is doing with dicts before returning them - or that the "order" you recieve them in will match the columns  You just got lucky in this case.